# iOS App working with BLE mini

Tags: ios, methods, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have connected my iOS app to a **BLE** Mini and it reaches the `didDiscoverCharacteristics` method.

I'm kind of confused on what is supposed to happen here. A couple of the examples I found use a for loop to run through the characteristics and when the correct one is found do something. Is there a way to find the specific ID of a characteristic?

Comment: I suggest you read through the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html) from beginning to end.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [**CBCentralManager**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CBCentralManager) and implement [**CBCentralManagerDelegate**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManagerDelegate_Protocol/translated_content/CBCentralManagerDelegate.html).

Then, in `didDiscoverPeripheral:` method examine the `CBPeripheral` object, check if that's the one you are looking for and do your stuff.

#### Implementation

1. Declare a property.

   ```
   @property(nonatomic, strong) CBCentralManager *centralManager;
   ```
2. Create a `CBCentralManager`.

   ```
   _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                          queue:nil];
   ```
3. Implement `CBCentralManagerDelegate` protocol.

   ```
   - (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)centralManager
   {
       if (centralManager.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
       {
           NSLog(@"Start scanning");

           // This will scan for all peripherals.
           [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil
                                                   options:nil];
       }
   }

   - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
    didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
        advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                     RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
   {
       NSLog(@"Peripheral: %@", peripheral);

       // Do stuff.
   }
   ```

Good luck.